# Can Ruby Observers be used to monitor a table continuously and trigger a scheduler

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

We have a table that stores all information regarding a scheduler, and the scheduler performs some action at some particular time everyday.

We have different schedulers, so we are storing all scheduler info in a table including the scheduler time (daily, weekly etc).

Can Ruby Observer monitor the scheduler time from table and triggers the scheduler at that particular time stored in table?

our table : `trigger_schedule`

```
id  Scheduler_name  Table_name   Operation   When        Time
1   Feed_scheduler  feeds        Insert      everyday    9.am
2   User_scheduler  users        delete      everyday    5.pm
3   Task_scheduler  tasks        Get         every       6 hrs
```

we have a `generic scheduler` :

```
trigger_schedule[:When] trigger_schedule[:Time] do 
  SchedulerAction.perform_scheduler_actions
end
```

We need some process that continuously check the `trigger_schedule` table for the "When" and "Time" column and automatically call the `generic scheduler` to perform the actions at the given time in table.

Comment: Can ruby code be invoked by database when data change? I think not. Probably the best you can do is to check for possibly updated data at regular intervals.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev  Even if the table `trigger_schedule` is not updated, I need to call the `generic scheduler` at that time stored in table.

in short, I need a mechanism that identifies the `When` and `Time` column and trigger `generic scheduler`

Comment: That mechanism is a different matter. This question is about monitoring changes, isn't it?

Comment: Even though I don't agree with your requirement, I think it's nasty but here's a potential solution for you - instead of Ruby checking the db, have the db execute an external script when the data changes - after all, it's the database that's the authority about the data here. What you need is MySQL [sys UDF](https://github.com/mysqludf/lib_mysqludf_sys). However, as with all things, it comes with negative sides.